# Golang and Mgo sort by $natural: -1

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm just trying to get the latest document in my collection in MongoDB with Golang and Mgo.

Document in my collection:

```
{
    "_id",
    "numbers" : {
        "fst",
        "snd",
        "thd"
    },
    "none" : [ 
        {
            "fst",
            "snd",
            "thd",
            "email"
        }
    ],
    "twoNums" : [ 
        {
            "fst",
            "snd",
            "thd",
            "email"
        }
    ],
    "threeNums" : [ 
        {
            "fst",
            "snd",
            "thd",
            "email"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried:

```
err := db.C("plays").Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"numbers": 1}).Sort("$natural:-1").Limit(1).One(&numbs)
```

And with space between $natural and "-1"

```
err := db.C("plays").Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"numbers": 1}).Sort("$natural: -1").Limit(1).One(&numbs)
```

In MongoDB shell it works perfect

```
db.getCollection('plays').find({}, {numbers: 1}).sort({$natural: -1}).limit(1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/view/head:/session.go#L2130) I guess it should be `-$natural` for the reverse sort:

```
err := db.C("plays")
  .Find(nil)
  .Select(bson.M{"numbers": 1})
  .Sort("-$natural")
  .Limit(1)
  .One(&numbs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the only one combination that i haven't tried:)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
db.C("plays").Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"numbers": 1}).Sort("$-natural").Limit(1).One(&numbs)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. The first inserted document is selected

Comment: Is it because `limit(1)` ?  @AntonKrovokhizhin

Comment: No, I need to take only the first document after a query. But I tried to remove limit(1) and it didn't help me.